# how to modify this line?

Tags: html

i want to add this code

```
 <body onload="start();">

        <div id="ticker-container" onmouseover="sspeed=0;" onmouseout="sspeed=resumesspeed">
        <div id="ticker"></div>
        </div>
```

want to add to this code

```
<body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
  <div class='body-fauxcolumns'>
    <div class='fauxcolumn-outer body-fauxcolumn-outer'>
    <div class='cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to provide a better explanation so that we can understand what you mean.

Comment: Hello, which code do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload="start();" expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
    <div id="ticker-container" onmouseover="sspeed=0;" onmouseout="sspeed=resumesspeed">
        <div id="ticker"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='body-fauxcolumns'>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer body-fauxcolumn-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
        <div class='cap-left'/>
        <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
```

Since I don't know where you want the ticker, I put it in the top.

**Edit:**

Same code but it's in the right sidebar:

```
<body onload="start();" expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
    <div class='body-fauxcolumns'>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer body-fauxcolumn-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
        <div class='cap-left'/>
        <div class='cap-right'>
            <div id="ticker-container" onmouseover="sspeed=0;" onmouseout="sspeed=resumesspeed">
                <div id="ticker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it worked tnks alot but the text inside it is disappear

Comment: Alright, then that would be a separate question unless you show us the javascript function start. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Dear i want it in the right side of my blog. i want to put news regarding my blog in it. rite now its on the top of my blog n look very very unpleasant on page. please help me

Comment: sir i send u the link of my page so that u can get idea what i want.... actually i want on the right side of my page the "news ticker" so that if some one click and want to read it http://sweethomespk.blogspot.com/